# Nginx- How can I serve my static content with https that has a proxy in location block?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

My server listen 443 port and redirects the requests to another port in the server. Also my server listen 80 port and displays a static content the user when they browse http://www.xxxx.com

But I want also to display static content when user browse https://www.xxxx.com

How can I manage this ? My Nginx config file is ;

```
server {

   listen 443 ssl; 
   server_name xxxx.com;
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

   location / {
expires off;
      proxy_pass http://backend;
   }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

   server_name xxxx.com;
   root /var/www/xxxx.com/html;
   index index.html;

   location / {
try_files $uri $uri/=404;
   }
}
```

I want to display my index.html file when user browse my website with https://www.xxxx.com and my proxy will continue to work at backend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can invoke a named location as the default action of your `try_files` statement.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
}
location @proxy {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.