# NGINX ignoring root when using proxy pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm having a bit of a problem with NGINX. I made a simple HTML that loads my application in a iframe hosted on `http://localhost:3000`.

Using the config below, localhost:3000 is proxied but root /var/www is ignored so I only get to see the application without any of my html.

What would be the correct way to proxy a url loaded inside an iframe?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/sub.mydomain.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name sub.mydomain.com;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5601/;
    }
}
```

Comment: The configuration in your question does not use or require a `root` directive, as all requests are proxied to `localhost:5601`. Your question mentions `localhost:3000` - is that a typo? Do you have files located in `/var/www/sub.mydomain.com/html/` which need to be served by this server instead of `localhost:5601`?

Comment: Sorry, 5601 is a type and it should be 3000. The reason I want root to be server is because localhost:3000 is loaded in an iframe. If I don't use root, the user will only see the app without the additional info from the html I want to show.

Comment: Are you looking for solution similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51492495/nginx-how-can-i-serve-my-static-content-with-https-that-has-a-proxy-in-location)?

Comment: Bit different I think. In my case the problem wasn't with the NGIX config but with my iframe. I had to exclude localhost from the src and after that it worked.