# Nginx proxy overrides default HTML files

Tags: nginx, proxy

I am trying to setup a proxy with docker-compose, which works just fine.

However.

I am hosting the proxy a "/" endpoint, which seems to override my default html files from the nginx root folder. The proxy server only have one endpoint with the url "/login"

How can I see my index.html? Can I override the proxy, that if some file exists, then show that file instead?

Hope you understand

Nginx conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;


                index index.html;
                root  /var/www/;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://flask-app:5000/;
        proxy_set_header Host "localhost";
    }
}
```

PS: If I remove the proxy I can see HTML files just fine.

**EDIT**

I tried this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    index index.html;
    root  /var/www/;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
    }
    location @proxy {
        proxy_pass http://flask-app:5000/;
    }

}
```

Is this how I was suppose to implement it?

**I get this error when I startup:**

"proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:12

nginx | nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:12

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51492495/nginx-how-can-i-serve-my-static-content-with-https-that-has-a-proxy-in-location/51497749#51497749).

Comment: It does not seem to work, please check my edit answer, would be great if you had an idea of whats wrong

Comment: Remove the trailing `/` from the `proxy_pass` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this in the config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    index index.html;
    root  /var/www/;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
    }
    location @proxy {
        proxy_pass http://flask-app:5000/;
    }

}
```

Thanks to Richard Smith