# How to use a block for all non-root paths in nginx config?

Tags: regex, nginx, url, wildcard-subdomain

In a single page app behind nginx, I'd like all non-root paths to be handled by an upstream server:

```
upstream socket_nodes {
    server 127.0.0.1:5000;
}
server {

listen 80;

index index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
 location whaeverelse {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://socket_nodes;
    }
}
```

What I've tried was to list all the `whateverelse` paths to a line like this:

```
location /(api|user|profile|about|login|logout|register) {...
```

Apart from being hackish, that did not work. 
I have also tried some wildcard regexps like this:

```
location  ~ ^/[0-9a-z] {
```

or even more excessive ones:

```
location  ~ ^/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W) {
```

with no success.
So I'm wondering what is the idiomatic way to do so?

Comment: Usually `location /` is used to represent *whatever else* with more specific `location` statements handling the exceptions. And, I do not understand what you mean by non-root paths.

Comment: @RichardSmith, by 'non-root path' , I mean any url other thatn `/`

Comment: So `index.html` is a static file? Presumably there are other static files too? And you want any other URI to be sent to the proxy?

Comment: Well as it is a SPA, the index.htm is the only static file, which fetches js and media.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51492495/nginx-how-can-i-serve-my-static-content-with-https-that-has-a-proxy-in-location/51497749#51497749).

Comment: @RichardSmith this one works.  Please answer and I'll accept it. Thanks a lot!