# nginx link 2 different locations with 2 different apps

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have a static html website used as a landing page and a fullstack react/node as a separated app.
What i wanna do is to use the landing page on "/" and everything that comes after that should redirect to the fullstack app.

here is my config file but it does not work

```
 server {
      server_name example.com
      index index.html index.htm;
      root /var/www/landing/;
      location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
      location ~/(.*)$ {
             proxy_pass http://localhost:2000;
      }
}
```

Comment: The regular expression `~/(.*)$` matches `/`, so basically any URI, so the `location /` block is never used. If you want to match just `/`, you would be better off using `location = /` with `location /` instead.

Comment: No, location / is pointing to my static html landing page on a different folder. I want everything that points to location /anything after that to be pointed to the other react js app on port 2000

Comment: Try: `location = / { try_files /index.html =404; } location / { proxy_pass ...; }`

Comment: @RichardSmith thank you it is working now but the landing page is not loading any css/images/js files

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51492495/nginx-how-can-i-serve-my-static-content-with-https-that-has-a-proxy-in-location/51497749#51497749).

Comment: @RichardSmith thank you very much you're a life saviour ! it works now ... have a good day